# Hypothesis Testing Skewness in two-sample cases

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, skewness

Anyone knows how to do hypothesis testing on skewness for two samples? Better in R please. The null hypothesis is the skewness of two groups is the same.

I've found the below two relevant posts, but they are not for two-samples I believe.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034776/hypothesis-testing-skewness-and-or-kurtosis-in-r
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-hypothesis-test-datas-skewness-and-or-kurtosis

Back ground: as a business we try to do some changes on our product. The success would be measured by reduced gap between median and mean of a metric. And we want to know how big the change is given a certain confidence level.

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to say that I'm also interested to know 1) how to calculate the required sample size I need in this case, and 2) can I get a p-value for the results?

Comment: Why, may I ask, are you specifically interested in testing skewness? This is quite odd. How about testing the shape of the overall distribution?

Comment: I think this should be addressed by looking at the sample estimate of skewness & the test would be whether or not the skewness is different from 0. We decide this by looking at how far from 0 the sample estimate of skewness is. To do this you need to know the distribution of the sample estimate under the null hypothesis. To do that I think you need to make some additional assumptions about the underlying distribution.

Comment: Our business is a job board. We are facing a problem that a small amount of job gets many applications while many get very little. We need to balance the needs between recruiter and jobseekers. So we're developing something to improve this situation without sacrificing the quality of job recommendation.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Is this case, how can we quantify the change to say how much we reduce the gap between median and mean, while also being confident the the Test variant actually is different from the Control, not by accident? My observed mean and median on either samples could be only a random number of a series of possible values of the total population. And I need certain confidence level on it - say 90%.

Comment: 1. It's important to state clearly early n that your concern relates specifically to the difference between mean and median. Unless accompanied by some adjective/qualifying phrase "skewness" will often tend to be interpreted to refer to moment skewness; on the other hand there are approaches to comparing skewness which would work for a nonparametric two sample test which also don't correspond directly to a mean minus median type measure.  2 Your concern seems primarily to relate to showing that there's a reduction in mean minus median, rather than in simply saying it's different from ... ctd

Comment: .... that seen in another sample. Are you interested in being able to say something like "the change in the mean-median difference is larger for treatment than it is for control"?

Comment: Hi Glen, yes this is almost exactly what I'm looking for - whether the mean-median difference is smaller for treatment than it is for control. We try to reduce the gap. And I thought by doing a two sample test on the moment skewness could solve the problem. But it's seemed you disagreed with it. So to solve the problem, what method would you recommend?